# Change colour of page controller during page swipe

Tags: swift

So I have three pages, each has its own background colour,

`UIColor.blue; UIColor.red; UIColor.yellow`

When I scroll from red to green, I want to fade into the green, I have already achieved that with this code. (Ignore the custom UIColor values, I've simplified the explanation)

```
public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let point = scrollView.contentOffset
        var percentComplete: CGFloat
        percentComplete = fabs(point.x - view.frame.size.width)/view.frame.size.width
        if percentComplete != 0{
            self.view.backgroundColor = fadeFromColor(fromColor: UIColor(red:0.20, green:0.60, blue:0.86, alpha:1.0), toColor: UIColor(red:0.91, green:0.30, blue:0.24, alpha:1.0), withPercentage: percentComplete)
        }
    }
    func fadeFromColor(fromColor: UIColor, toColor: UIColor, withPercentage: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        var fromRed: CGFloat = 0.0
        var fromGreen: CGFloat = 0.0
        var fromBlue: CGFloat = 0.0
        var fromAlpha: CGFloat = 0.0

        fromColor.getRed(&fromRed, green: &fromGreen, blue: &fromBlue, alpha: &fromAlpha)

        var toRed: CGFloat = 0.0
        var toGreen: CGFloat = 0.0
        var toBlue: CGFloat = 0.0
        var toAlpha: CGFloat = 0.0

        toColor.getRed(&toRed, green: &toGreen, blue: &toBlue, alpha: &toAlpha)

        //calculate the actual RGBA values of the fade colour
        var red = (toRed - fromRed) * withPercentage + fromRed
        var green = (toGreen - fromGreen) * withPercentage + fromGreen
        var blue = (toBlue - fromBlue) * withPercentage + fromBlue
        var alpha = (toAlpha - fromAlpha) * withPercentage + fromAlpha

        // return the fade colour
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
```

Problem is, I don't know how to make it fade back. It turns to its old colour.

How would I mke it fade back and fourth? Thanks

Comment: You should just reverse your logic of calculating the fade colour `RGBA` values and use that for fading back to the original colour.

Comment: Problem is, if I have multiple pages, I don't know how to also get the destination to work out what colour to go to.

Comment: So do you have a problem with your colour calculation that is shown in the question or with navigation on a page controller?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is very close — there are just a few modifications needed in the `scrollViewDidScroll` function.

To make the code work for any number of pages, you'll need logic to determine which page the scrollview is on based on its content offset.

```
public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let lowerIndex = Int(floor(offset / scrollView.frame.width))
    let upperIndex = Int(ceil(offset / scrollView.frame.width))
    guard lowerIndex >= 0, upperIndex <= colors.count - 1 else { return }
    let percentComplete = (offset - CGFloat(lowerIndex) * scrollView.frame.width) / scrollView.frame.width
    scrollView.backgroundColor = fadeFromColor(fromColor: colors[lowerIndex], toColor: colors[upperIndex], withPercentage: percentComplete)
}
```

This implementation calculates a `lowerIndex` and `upperIndex`, which represent the pages that are above and below the current offset at any given point. These indexes are used to grab the colors from an array of colors and mix them together.

**Demonstration Gif**

[image: Animated Example of the Working Color ScrollView Paging Code]

Here is the full, working implementation which can be easily tested out in a Swift Playground:

**Swift Playground Code**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    let colors = [UIColor(red:0.20, green:0.60, blue:0.86, alpha:1.0), UIColor(red:0.91, green:0.30, blue:0.24, alpha:1.0), UIColor.yellow]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.frame = view.bounds
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(colors.count) * scrollView.frame.width, height: scrollView.frame.height)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = colors[0]
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

    }

    public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let lowerIndex = Int(floor(offset / scrollView.frame.width))
        let upperIndex = Int(ceil(offset / scrollView.frame.width))
        guard lowerIndex >= 0, upperIndex <= colors.count - 1 else { return }
        let percentComplete = (offset - CGFloat(lowerIndex) * scrollView.frame.width) / scrollView.frame.width
        scrollView.backgroundColor = fadeFromColor(fromColor: colors[lowerIndex], toColor: colors[upperIndex], withPercentage: percentComplete)
    }

    func fadeFromColor(fromColor: UIColor, toColor: UIColor, withPercentage: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        var fromRed: CGFloat = 0.0
        var fromGreen: CGFloat = 0.0
        var fromBlue: CGFloat = 0.0
        var fromAlpha: CGFloat = 0.0

        fromColor.getRed(&fromRed, green: &fromGreen, blue: &fromBlue, alpha: &fromAlpha)

        var toRed: CGFloat = 0.0
        var toGreen: CGFloat = 0.0
        var toBlue: CGFloat = 0.0
        var toAlpha: CGFloat = 0.0

        toColor.getRed(&toRed, green: &toGreen, blue: &toBlue, alpha: &toAlpha)

        // calculate the actual RGBA values of the fade colour
        let red = (toRed - fromRed) * withPercentage + fromRed
        let green = (toGreen - fromGreen) * withPercentage + fromGreen
        let blue = (toBlue - fromBlue) * withPercentage + fromBlue
        let alpha = (toAlpha - fromAlpha) * withPercentage + fromAlpha

        // return the fade colour
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }

}
```

To make this code run in the playground's live view like the gif above, you will also need the following code:

```
let vc = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

Comment: Thanks, I dropped in your code but it didn't really work as expected, it overlayed itself on top of my other code, and stopped my page control from functioning. Thanks for your help though, I'll see if I can adapt it

Comment: @Will Yeah I created a new scroll view in the playground example so I could get it to work. All you need to do is copy my `scrollViewDidScroll` function and the array of colors.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried that, but ended up with this: https://gyazo.com/b45b8ed1704a980ea5d6365b2e53f266

Comment: @Will If you only have two pages, only put two colors in the `colors` array. Is the scrollview's width the full width of the view? My solution makes that assumption.

Comment: Yes, the scrollview is the same width. When I put only two colours in the array, I got even weirder behaviour. I won't bother you any more, I'll try and figure something out. If I figure it out, I'll leave a comment and accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: No, sorry. I ended up having to scrap the idea but it caused more problems than it solved.